# Angular: Push Generated Timestamp on Submitted Form

Tags: json, angularjs, firebase

I've written a form in Angular that sends submitted data in my form to an object called `places` in my Firebase.

**HTML**

```
<form role="form" name="addPlaceForm" ng-submit="createHospital(newHospital)">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter title here" ng-model="newHospital.title">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
var rootRef = new Firebase('URL');
var placesRef = rootRef.child('places');

function createHospital(hospital) {
  placesRef.push(hospital);
}
```

Is there a way I can push a generated timestamp called `created_at` to my `places` object when it's submitted?

```
"created_at" : "2014-07-15T01:52:33Z"
```

And what about other automated data, like pushing a unique ID, for example.

Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right when you add the hospital to the array you can create the two parameters you want:

```
function createHospital(hospital) {
    var newHospital = angular.copy(hospital);
    newHospital.created_at = new Date();
    newHospital.ID = ID_GENERATE_FUNCTION();
    placesRef.push(newHospital);
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. The item gets added to my Firebase, but neither the `created_at` or `ID` are present.

Comment: Add a console log directly after the push. Also make sure you are pushing the newHospital and not hospital.

Comment: I'm getting a `ID_GENERATE_FUNCTION is not defined` in the console log. http://plnkr.co/edit/kfH4I5Fzy2Ma14FjQj67?p=preview

Comment: You have to create that function yourself :)

Comment: Ahh, okay, that makes a bit more sense (duh!) :s. The date is added to the object in the console log, is there any reason it's not added to the Firebase object, but the `title` is?

Comment: I do not know, sorry. Perhaps have it convert the date object to a string.

Comment: Ended up storing the `new Date()` in a variable called `date` and using `toISOString()` on my `date` var to return a string and convert to my much-preferred ISO format. Thanks for all your help! +1

Answer (score 2):

### Is there a way I can push a generated timestamp called created_at to my places object when it's submitted?

An alternative to passing the timestamp from the client is to use Firebase's built-in [`Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/servervalue/timestamp.html), which is documented as:

> A placeholder value for auto-populating the current timestamp (time since the Unix epoch, in milliseconds) by the Firebase servers.

So you could do something like this:

```
function createHospital(hospital) {
  hospital.created_at = Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
  placesRef.push(hospital);
}
```

See this post for more information:https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-06-17-howto-build-a-presence-system.html

### What about other automated data, like pushing a unique ID?

When you call the Firebase `push` method a unique ID is already generated for you. The [documentation for `push`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/push.html):

> Generates a new child location using a unique name and returns a Firebase reference to it.

This ID is guaranteed by Firebase to be unique, specifically so that your application doesn't have to worry about it. The `push`-generated ID takes a form like `-JXd1pbUU89Xbd4BYvx6`, `-JZoLcBKnd1A8Gn-ZP0I`, etc.

I would recommend sticking to that ID, instead of generating your own additional ID. If you prefer to to generate your own IDs, I would solely use that ID and use it to name your node instead of letting `push` generate one for you:

```
var newID = ID_GENERATE_FUNCTION();
placesRef.child(newID).set(hospital);
```

Note that here too I don't store the newID **in** the hospital object.

Comment: This was very helpful too! I wanted to use convert the date to an ISO string format anyways, so I guess I wouldn't need to use Firebase's built-in option, or would I? In regards to the ID, I wanted a 6-digit unique ID that I could use on the URL, like so: `site.com/245372/hospital-name`. Am I right in thinking it's probably best to store this `id` in the hospital object?

Comment: I prefer to store things in only one place. If you use the self-generated ID as the name of the Firebase object, that means I wouldn't store it as a property of each object. But that may just be a personal preference.